# How to customize permission for a group on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, windows-server-2016, security-groups

I want to create a "restricted" administrator group that can only run the privileged PowerShell cmdlet `Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics`. Does Windows Server support such level of granularity? And in general, how do I create a customized security group (specifying which task members can perform and which they can't)? (Not in AD.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Just Enough Administration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/jea/overview), with it you can restrict users to perform certain administrative tasks without being a member of the administrator group.

You need to learn a bit about JEA first, but it is a powerful new tool to limit what administrators can do.